Reconstructing RF signal with data using libhackrf
I am trying to recreate a signal I initially captured with Universal Radio Hacker (URH) using libhackrf. From what I can tell I have implemented the following characteristics within my code:
Carrier Frequency: 6.104Khz
Carrier Phase: 0 degrees
Symbol length:20
Sample rate 2M
Modulation type: ASK
Bits per symbol: 1
Amplitude in %: 0/100
Centre Frequency: 434375000  

It uses this data which was captured from an ASK signal and is Manchester encoded. For now I am just trying to replay the signal, so I have not re-encoded the data.
855555540a58dc58ddddbf8ab1ffffccf7fffe2dffc5077bf6cdff9f52

The signal however is not being received by the receiver. I expect the signal identifier to be displayed within an HMI when it is received. I have replayed the signal from URH and confirmed the receiver is working.
Any idea what I'm missing here to get this working? I've removed everything I don't think is necessary for the question, but please let me know and I can add it back in as needed.
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <hackrf.h>
#include "hackrf_controller.h"
#include "conversions.h"

// Default variable values
int SAMPLE_RATE = 2000000;  // Hz
int FREQ = 434375000;       // Hz. Default 434.375 MHz
int WAVE_FREQ = 1000;       // 1 kHz sine wave
int AMPLITUDE = 127;        // Hz
int TX_PERIOD_SECS = 10;    // Seconds 
uint8_t* payload = NULL;
int message_len = 0;

...SNIP...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    set_general_arguments(argc, argv);
    set_operation_arguments(argc, argv);


    // Free the payload memory if it was dynamically allocated
    if (payload != NULL) {
        free(payload);
    }

    return 0;
}

void set_general_arguments(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

        if (i + 1 >= argc) {
            return;
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--frequency") == 0) {
            FREQ = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--tx-seconds") == 0) {
            TX_PERIOD_SECS = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--sample-rate") == 0) {
            SAMPLE_RATE = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--wave-freq") == 0) {
            WAVE_FREQ = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--amplitude") == 0) {
            AMPLITUDE = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
 void set_operation_arguments(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--normal") == 0) {
            int result = configure_hackrf_parameters();
            if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            const char *hex_string = "855555540a58dc58ddddbf8ab1ffffccf7fffe2dffc5077bf6cdff9f52";
            size_t byte_array_length = strlen(hex_string) / 2;

            // Allocate memory for the payload
            payload = (uint8_t*)malloc(byte_array_length * sizeof(uint8_t));
            if (payload == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            // Convert the hex string to a byte array
            hex_to_bytes(hex_string, payload);
            message_len = byte_array_length;

            tx_data();
        }

    }
    }

}

And my hackrf controller:
// hackrfcontroller.c

#include <hackrf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "hackrf_controller.h"
#include "conversions.h"

#ifndef M_PI
    #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

#define NOISE_LEVEL 0.1     
#define SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL 20
#define BITS_PER_SYMBOL 1
#define SYMBOL_RATE (FREQ / SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL)
#define CARRIER_FREQ 6104000 

// Function declarations
int tx_callback_no_data(hackrf_transfer* transfer);
int tx_callback(hackrf_transfer* transfer);
void print_time();
uint8_t* append_crc(const uint8_t *data, size_t length);
void print_payload(const uint8_t *payload, size_t length);
uint8_t* manchester_encode(const uint8_t *data, size_t length, size_t *encoded_length);

// Define global variables if needed
hackrf_device *device = NULL;
extern uint8_t* payload;  // Extern reference to global payload
extern int message_len;   // Extern reference to global message_len


int tx_data() {
    print_payload(payload, message_len);
    int result = hackrf_start_tx(device, tx_callback, NULL);
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hackrf_start_tx() failed: %s\n", hackrf_error_name(result));
        free(payload);  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < TX_PERIOD_SECS; j++) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    hackrf_stop_tx(device);
    free(payload);  
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


// Callback function for transmitting the ASK-modulated signal
int tx_callback(hackrf_transfer *transfer) {
    generate_ask_signal(payload, message_len, transfer->buffer, transfer->valid_length);
    return 0;
}


// Configures the HackRF device parameters
int configure_hackrf_parameters() {
    int result = hackrf_init();
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hackrf_init() failed: %s\n", hackrf_error_name(result));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    result = hackrf_open(&device);
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hackrf_open() failed: %s\n", hackrf_error_name(result));
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    result = hackrf_set_sample_rate_manual(device, SAMPLE_RATE, 1);
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hackrf_set_sample_rate_manual() failed: %s\n", hackrf_error_name(result));
        hackrf_close(device);
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    result = hackrf_set_freq(device, FREQ);
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hackrf_set_freq() failed: %s\n", hackrf_error_name(result));
        hackrf_close(device);
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Set Bandwidth to 2 MHz
    result = hackrf_set_baseband_filter_bandwidth(device, SAMPLE_RATE);  // 2 MHz bandwidth
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        hackrf_close(device);
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    // Set RF Gain (LNA Gain) to 0
    result = hackrf_set_lna_gain(device, 0);
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        hackrf_close(device);
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    // Set IF Gain (VGA Gain) to 23
    result = hackrf_set_vga_gain(device, 23);
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        hackrf_close(device);
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    // Set Bias Tee to Disabled (0)
    result = hackrf_set_antenna_enable(device, 0);  // 0 to disable, 1 to enable
    if (result != HACKRF_SUCCESS) {
        hackrf_close(device);
        hackrf_exit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    hackrf_set_amp_enable(device, 1);
    hackrf_set_txvga_gain(device, 20);

    return HACKRF_SUCCESS;
}


// Used for debugging only
void print_payload(const uint8_t *payload, size_t length) {
    printf("Payload: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", payload[i]);  // Print each byte as a 2-digit hexadecimal number
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// ASK Modulation function
void generate_ask_signal(uint8_t *data, size_t data_length, uint8_t *buffer, size_t buffer_length) {
    double carrier_phase = 0.0;
    double carrier_step = 2.0 * M_PI * 6104000 / SAMPLE_RATE;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer_length; i++) {
        // Determine the current bit from the data (1 or 0)
        uint8_t bit = data[i / (buffer_length / data_length)];

        // Generate the ASK-modulated signal
        int16_t signal;
        if (bit == 1) {
            signal = (int16_t)(AMPLITUDE * (sin(carrier_phase) + 1) / 2); // Modulated signal for '1'
        } else {
            signal = 0; // No carrier for '0'
        }

        // Add noise to the signal
        float noise = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 2.0 - 1.0; // Generate noise between -1 and 1
        signal += (int16_t)(NOISE_LEVEL * noise * 127);

        // Ensure the signal is within 8-bit range
        if (signal > 127) {
            signal = 127;
        } else if (signal < -128) {
            signal = -128;
        }

        buffer[i] = (uint8_t)(signal & 0xFF); // Store the final signal
        carrier_phase += carrier_step;
        if (carrier_phase >= 2.0 * M_PI) {
            carrier_phase -= 2.0 * M_PI;
        }
    }
}

